# How should I validate this correctly?

Tags: python, validation

```
input1= input("Enter a word or number: ")
input2= input("Enter another word or number: ")
check1= input1.isdigit()
check2= input2.isdigit()
def x(input1, input2):
    if check1== True and check2==True:
        if input1>input2:
            return "The first number is bigger"
        elif input2>input1:
            return "The second number is bigger"
        else:
            return "Both numbers are same size"
        
    elif check1== False and check2== False: 
        for i in input1:
            y=i.isdigit()
            if y== True:
                return "Enter a word or a number"
            else:
                for j in input2:
                    z=j.isdigit()
                    if z== True:
                        return "Enter a word or a number"
                    else:
                        if len(input1)>len(input2):
                            return "The first word is longer"
                        elif len(input1)==len(input2):
                            return "The words are the same length" 
                        else:
                            return "The second word is longer"
    else:
        return "Can't compare"
x(input1, input2)
y = x(input1, input2)
print(y)
```

'''
This is a function which asks the user to input two values and then gives the longer word if the user inputs two words or gives the bigger number when the user enters two numbers. It returns can't
compare if the user enters a word and a number, however the problem I am facing is I am unable to validate when the user enters something like Ml3003322 or qwewe9qw92222. Could anyone suggest possible solutions?
'''

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code as a text.

Comment: What do you mean "unable to validate"? What problem are you facing with values like that? Your code treats them as strings and compares lengths, which is what I would expect.

Comment: When I enter values like Ml3003322 or qwewe9qw92222 (ie that start with a letter and contain numbers) I would like the code to print 'Enter a word or number' however this doesn't work, it returns that the second word is longer, only works for inputs that start with numbers like 32i3isdfsfd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [isalpha](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) and [isdecimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal) to test if a given string contains all letters or digits.
Uasge example:

```
def is_word_number(s):
    if s.isalpha():
        return 'word'
    if s.isdecimal():
        return 'number'
    return 'error'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid "mixed words" as per your comment, the you can create a function like this:

```py
def check_mixed(x):
    ''' check mixed words 
    
    return: True (if good), False (if mixed)
    '''

    numbers = '01234567890'
    letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

    
    l, m = 0, 0     # count letters an numbers
    for i in x:
        if i in numbers:
            l = l+1     # number found
        if i.lower() in letters:
            m = m + 1   # letter found
        if l>1 and m>1:
            return False 
    return True

# example
a = check_mixed('12345')
b = check_mixed('abcde')
c = check_mixed('Ml3003322')

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

this returns

```
True
True
False
```